# Kotlin data-binding issue type missmatch

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I am trying to implement data-binding in my small kotlin project in a android. But getting error when assign viewmodel to databinding.

I have three class in this small project
1. User -  A data model class
2. ActivityMainViewModel  -  View Model class
3. MainActivity - Class that will implement the data-binding

But in MainActivity.kt i am getting error when set the viewmodel to binding.

User.kt

```
class User() {
    var emailId: String= ""
    var password: String= ""

    constructor(emailId: String, password: String) : this() {
        this.emailId = emailId
        this.password = password
    }
}
```

---

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        var myviewmodel= MainActivityViewModel()
        val userObj = User("abc@gmail.com","123344")
        myviewmodel.setUser(userObj)

        binding.viewModel = myviewmodel
    }
}
```

---

MainActivityViewModel.kt

```
class MainActivityViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    val userObj = User()

    fun setUser(user: User){
        userObj.emailId = user.emailId
        userObj.password = user.password
    }
}
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <data>
               <variable
                        name="viewModel"
                        type="testing.justrade.databindingissue.ViewModel.MainActivityViewModel"
                />
        </data>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".View.MainActivity">
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hello World!"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I am getting this error.

```
E:\--------------------------/ MainActivity.kt: (21, 17): Cannot access class 'ViewModel.MainActivityViewModel'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Type mismatch: inferred type is testing.justrade.databindingissue.ViewModel.MainActivityViewModel but ViewModel.MainActivityViewModel? was expected
```

I have attached the screen shot of error in blow link -

https://ibb.co/Y25dbTn

Comment: Provide your **xml file**.

Comment: Please add your error into the question.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I have added

Comment: @tynn  I have added error in question

Comment: Are you having multiple declaration of `MainAcitivityViewModel` in different package directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not name your packages with *CamelCase* as defined in the [*Java Naming Conventions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.

Especially when using the *Android Data Binding Library* this is relevant. In your case `ViewModel` is interpreted as a class and therefore `ViewModel.MainActivityViewModel` as a static inner class of it.

You'd have to rename your package into `viewmodel` to make it work.